# Blinking of Caps Lock key and F11 and F12 keys being constantly on, on a new HP DV7 notebook

Tags: keyboard, laptop-repair, hp-pavilion, maintenance

I believe it is related to a faulty keyboard that has very unstable behavior in regards to letter "N".

History:

- Laptop was fine (CPU and GPU and RAM perfectly stable even on heavier conditions (high end gaming))
- Key 'N' started acting up. It would repeat itself and it would stop if "meddled with" or any other key around it was pressed (the "around it" thing points that it is not a problem isolated to "N", it affected other keys as well).
- Reboots were fine for a while.
- A rare reboot occurred with the previously mentioned condition "Blinking of Caps Lock key and F11 and F12 keys being constantly on" (also a beeping noise without a pattern, just repeating). It would not boot.
- Rebooting again sometimes made it work. The computer was perfectly stable until rebooted again.
- After a while (2 days) the letter "N" became totally unstable. It would repeat itself almost constantly and pressing random keys (such as "ENTER") would stop it.
- Rebooting became harder to become successful.
  (same conditions with leds mentioned, also a beeping noise without a pattern, just repeating)
- I finally managed to boot either out of luck or after pressing "ENTER" while booting/powering on.

Any thoughts?

- I am now afraid to turn it off.
- The letter "N" is now totally dead which makes me even more afraid to turn it off and on again (in case it never boots at all).

I do not know if it will boot without a keyboard at all. Some say it will but it's circumstantial and I don't want to risk it unnecessarily.

- I have ordered a keyboard that is compatible. I'm still uncertain if I should turn it off for it but at least I'll have a better solution than hoping it will have no keyboard at all (and rely on a USB keyboard) or worse, not boot at all, which is what I really dread of. I do not have an alternative computer.

Comment: Sounds liek a busted keyboard.  Have you contacted HP (since it's new, and probably still under warranty)?   Does the problem continue in Safe Mode, or in another OS (ie: a Linux LiveCD)?   If so, it's definitely a hardware problem. :)

Comment: It occurs - when it occurs - very early, no process beyond that, no video or boot or BIOS menu. It is under warranty but I do not want to part with it for 20 days if it can be fixed easily otherwise. Also, I do not want to deal with a service department that may think the key was dead because of user fault and go full circle or make me pay a lot.

Comment: Well, get a replacement keyboard and replace it, because it sounds like a broken/malfunctioning keyboard.  Luckily notebook keyboards are usually cheap (if they aren't weird shaped, or have a track-point mouse).  You also may want to consider looking around for a more 'local' HP repair centre (local to you) and just deal with them directly; that can help eliminate many of the "20 days" you're expecting (we're an authorized Toshiba notebook repair place and we have most repairs done in 24-48 hours).

Comment: If you can return it to place of purchase for a refund or another new unit, this is what I would do, HP warranty support is horrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a keyboard. Faulty key was repeating itself.